# Firebug : Problem with jQuery in WordPress admin panel

Tags: jquery, admin-menu

I'm trying to make my first plugin and I have a problem with firebug. When I use firebug console in WP Admin Panel doesn´t work correctly. For example when I use the selector $('#wpbody') the console return null value. The WP panel include jQuery library and I don´t know why firebug works wrong.

Any advice or sugestion?

Tested with WP 3.1.3 and 3.2.1

Thanks,
Marcos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses jQuery in `noConflict()` mode, so `$` is not available for use in Firebug console. Just use `jQuery('#wpbody')` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much, works correctly now :). I have much to learn ...
Thanks for your help.
All the best,
Marcos.